# Is there anyway to get sample data from NEST thermostat or SMOKE CO devices ?

Tags: android, python, nest-api

I am trying to some analysis on NEST based thermostat and SMOKE CO detectors. How to get the sample data of temparture recordings, humidity etc without purchasing the device, looking for sample datasets with some dummy customer details.

If not at least a way from virtual devices?

Answer (score 2):

The [Nest Chrome Extension](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/chrome-extension) is what you are looking for. It will let you create virtual devices and twiddle the bits on them.

Comment: Thanks David, I found the same after posting the question. I was yet to answer to my question. Glad you confirmed it.

Thanks again!